# Using Minion Pro with Classicthesis

Tags: xetex, classicthesis, input-encodings

Good afternoon, I bought Minion Pro fonts (regular and italics) in order to use them with a classicthesis document. And following the instructions you gave me recently, I run with Xelatex but it did not work. Where do I have to put the following command ? `\setmainfont{Minion Pro}`

I think there is an issue in my preamble. May you examine it, please?

```
% book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{epigraph} 
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{graphicx}  %% For \scalebox
\usepackage[tight,french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{../classicthesis} % ,manychapters
%\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\scshape}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=4cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\newcounter{qcounter}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=npr, title=Index des noms propres] 
\makeindex[name=mat, title=Index des matières] 

\renewcommand\textflush{flushright}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newlength\epitextskip
\pretocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\epigraph}{\@epitext{#1}\\}{\@epitext{#1}\\[\epitextskip]}{}{}
\makeatother

\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
\setlength\epitextskip{2ex}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.8\textwidth}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{\relax}
{\mbox{}\oldmarginpar{\vspace*{4\baselineskip}%
\color{halfgray}\scalebox{1.2}{\chapterNumber\thechapter}}}
{0pt}%
{\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{1.2\baselineskip}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      

\FrenchFootnotes
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lineno}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}

\frontmatter
\begin{document}

%   \pagestyle{scrheadings}
%   \manualmark
%   \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}      {\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
```

Comment: Where did you install the fonts? Did you activate the fonts?

Comment: I installed the fonts into the fonts book on my mac. In the meantime, I succeeded in running my document, bit I have a big problem with the characters in my bibliography. All are not recognized.

Comment: And what would some of those characters that are giving you a big problem be? Do you use bibtex or biblatex/biber?

Comment: The characters I had to modify are « ». I had to replace them by " ". For my bibliography, I use bibtex and the following package \usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite} I can't compile anymore my initial bib file. I'm trying to rebuild it step by step.

Comment: I found a solution. My problem was in relation with some characters of my bibliography. I had the following one which was not recognized : @inbook{Castarède1983,
   author = {Castarède, Marie-France},
   title = {L'entretien clinique à visée de recherche},
   booktitle = {L'entretien clinique},
   editor = {Chiland, Colette},
   publisher = {Presses Universitaires de France},
   address = {Paris, France},
   pages = {118-145},
   year = {1983},
} So, I suppress the accent "è" and replace it by castarede1983. And it works.

Comment: ... many characters aren't recognized using xelatex : œ, « », ’.

Comment: Nor the following letter : "È".

Comment: When using XeLaTeX, you shouln't load the `inputenc` package at all. Instead, make sure that the file is UTF8-encoded, and you should be in business for the most part. Regarding bib entries, it looks like you've found the solution that works with bibtex: don't use accented characters in the entry's key.

Comment: But I need to compile with the following packages : \usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

Comment: Why must your document be input-encoded as `applemac`? Why can't its input encoding scheme be converted to `utf8`?

Comment: @Mico: I would even ask more: how can Mac users still use AppleMac encoding  these days. That goes against portability. All modern systems understand utf8!

Comment: @dormi Three things: 1. You need to ensure to install the fonts in the right directory, 2. You need to use a decent codification, I don't know if you use TeXshop or another editor, but you can recodify easily all your `*.tex` files with Sublime Text, by example. This can also avoid some of your problems. And 3. finally don't add `inputenc` if you really want to use `XeLaTeX`.

Comment: @Aradnix : 2 : what do you mean by "a decent codification" ? Do you suspect any problem with my preamble ? I've been working with Texshop on a mac for years now, without any problem. There is another method to use minion pro without compiling with xelatex, but I thought Xelatex did it well. Why can't I have the characters I need with Xelatex ?

Comment: @domi If you read the comments above from Mico and Bernanrd you could understand that you're preamble isn't right. The main problem in my opinion is that XeLaTeX does NOT uses/need the `inputenc` package. Isn't obvious but when you understand what does XeLaTeX and how it works, than you'll see the reason.

Comment: @domi Now, in terms of encoding `applemac` is from the 90's, if I remember correctly TeXShop uses `RomanMac` or something like, which is nice if you work on mac only (in my case I work on Mac, Linux and windows and utf8 is basic to avoid encoding problems). On the other hand, I'm not sure if `XeLaTeX` can be properly encoded to `RomanMac` less even `applemac` but you would have to check the documentation to be sure.

Comment: Following your suggestions, I added that command to my preamble (just after \documentclass) : \XeTeXinputencoding iso-8859-1 and it works well. But I don't know if it's a right command.

Answer (score 1):

Macs have used unicode fonts for years. I'd try to isolate your problem by setting up a simple document like the one below. Check that it compiles and displays the font(s) correctly, then incorporate the settings into your file(s).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Minion Pro}


\begin{document}

The quick brown fox \dots{}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified my preamble, following many suggestions you made. Therefore, this is my new preamble and... it works nice :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,twoside,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\XeTeXinputencoding iso-8859-1
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{epigraph} 
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{graphicx}  %% For \scalebox
\usepackage[tight,french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\scshape}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=4cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\newcounter{qcounter}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=npr, title=Index des noms propres] 
\makeindex[name=mat, title=Index des matières] 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
    {\relax}
    {\mbox{}\oldmarginpar{\vspace*{4\baselineskip}%
    \color{halfgray}\scalebox{1.2}{\chapterNumber\thechapter}}}
    {0pt}%
    {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{1.2\baselineskip}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      

 \renewcommand\textflush{flushright}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newlength\epitextskip
\pretocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\epigraph}{\@epitext{#1}\\}{\@epitext{#1}\\[\epitextskip]}{}{}
\makeatother

\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
\setlength\epitextskip{2ex}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.8\textwidth}


\FrenchFootnotes
\usepackage{lineno}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}
\frontmatter
\begin{document}

%   \pagestyle{scrheadings}
%   \manualmark
%   \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
```